# Use VST in Python for key detection

Tags: python, audio, vst

I have VST I bought from https://www.hornetplugins.com/plugins/hornet-songkey-mk2/ that works pretty when I use it with a DAW Software like Reaper or Steinberg.

Is there a decent way to load this Plugin in a python environment, feed it live audio data and then evaluate the scale?

I have zero knowledge how VSTs work, so any input would be great.